# C# DataGridView (populated using a DataSource) not saving to Database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, save, datasource

I have a form which I want to serve the purpose that the user can remove and edit (not add) rows from a database table, "Users". I have created a form and a DataSource in VS2010, the DataSource was created using the new DataSource wizard. From this I dragged and dropped the DataGridView for  the Users table in the DataSource windowstrip to the form.

The issue I have is that when I run the application, the data will load into the DataGridView fine, but when i delete or edit a row and click save it does not update the database.

I am an novice user so I'm sure I doing something stupid or naive - do i need to add some sql calls in here?

Any ideas?

[image]

```
public partial class EditUsers : Form
{
    public EditUsers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'debenhamsProjectOfficeDatabaseDataSet.Users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.debenhamsProjectOfficeDatabaseDataSet.Users);

    }

    private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.debenhamsProjectOfficeDatabaseDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more flexible way to populate your datagrid view with your database is to use a connection string.

Right click on your project file in solution explorer and add an new item. Add a class and name it connection.cs. In here type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Your_Project_Name
{
class Connection
{
    string ConnectionString;
    public Connection()
    {
        ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        "Data Source=C:/User/somefolder/Your_Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

    }
    public string getConnection()
    {
        return ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Now add using `System.Data.OleDb;` to your headers at the top of your form1.

Now in `public partial class EditUsers : Form` put

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        Connection c;
```

Finally in `private void EditUsers_Load` type in

```
c = new Connection();
            connect.ConnectionString = c.getConnection();
```